# Chrome extensions, how to uniquely identify extension installation

Tags: session, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome extension that will require a user login.

I suppose I can have the user login and then give them a unique session key to store in their chrome extension localstorage[].

Is there anyway to tell if someone is trying to use someone else's session key on a different computer? Does Chrome have a unique variable somewhere I can access to tell that this wasn't the original chrome installation that was being used when the session key was created? (i.e. force re-login and invalidate the session-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome does not have a unique install key that is accessible through a JavaScript API. Instead you should authenticate users. [Google Accounts through OpenId](http://code.google.com/chrome/webstore/docs/identify_user.html) is a recommended method. You can ignore the parts specific to payment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are your security requirements. But if you just want a very basic level to make a little bit harder to share the login key, than I guess you could do something like this:

1. Create a unique random key for the user when he installs your
   extension.
2. Store that key on the localStorage and then match a
   login key with this unique random key you generated.
3. If the unique
   random key is different than someone else is trying to access the
   account.

Comment: Is there some code that only runs at install time, or is that logic that we must implement (e.g. using a conditional statement on every load)?